# Flutter Connectivity_Plus MissingPluginException No implementation found for method check on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/connectivity))

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, wifi

I am trying to get the user connection and am getting this error. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

Future<String> LoadData() async {
  //First, check for connectivity
  final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  return '';
}
```

PUBSPEC.yaml

```
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.6
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to restart the app or do the following step

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
flutter run
```